# How do I convert .app to .pkg on a mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I plan to mass deploy a piece of software, (Mathematica), but the .dmg includes a .app file instead of a .pkg file which is what I need.

The guide below shows how to do it with Google Chrome, but I can't figure out the correct paths for Mathematica.
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-terminal-to-create-packages-for-software-deployment/

sudo pkgbuild —install-location /Applications —component /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app ./Desktop/Google\ Chrome.pkg

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out the path of the `.app` file in your volume.

1. Mount the `.dmg` by double clicking it.
2. In Terminal, run `cd /Volumes` and see the name of the mounted volume.
3. Run `cd VOLUME_NAME`, where `VOLUME_NAME` is the name you found in 2). Continue to `cd` if there are multiple levels, noting down the directory names.

You should end up with something along the lines of:

```
sudo pkgbuild --install-location /Applications --component 
/Volumes/Mathematica/Mathematica.app ./Desktop/Google\ Mathematica.pkg
```

The above is assuming the volume name and the app are the same, and there's only one directory. Remember to use `\` if the directory has a space in it. For example, `Google\ Chrome`.

Comment: Just tried this with Google Chrome; works great   For this simple task sure beats the $100 alternative; thanks!  By the way, `sudo` not needed; at least it worked for me without it.

Answer (score 0):

I work closely with the Chrome team. Please use this link for the Chrome on Mac .pkg file,

https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/#mac-pkg